# Send to ngChange value from option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple select where there are hardcoded values, 4,8,12 and on change i want to trigger some angular action.

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-change="setPageSize()">
    <option class="resultsList" value="4">4</option>
    <option class="resultsList" value="8">8</option>
    <option class="resultsList" value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

I need to send value of selected option to the setPageSize function, but i have no idea how.

I mean, what should be in brackets?

setPageSize($index); or what?

Comment: you can use `$scope.selected` inside `setPageSize` method.

Comment: Rasalom is correct. I see no value in passing a variable that is already part of the $scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, you are assigning `selected` to `ng-model`, you should be able just to use it:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-change="setPageSize(selected)">
    <option class="resultsList" value="4">4</option>
    <option class="resultsList" value="8">8</option>
    <option class="resultsList" value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works of course, but I don't see the value in sending a scope level object to a scope level function. setPageSize() can just as easily get $scope.selected itself...

Answer (score 1):

you wl be able to use it below is the plunker code

```
$scope.setPageSize = function(selected){
    console.log(selected)
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tur5PrBHPuMHZBAVoazR?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In the function you can simply use the $scope.selected.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.setPageSize = function(){
              $scope.change = $scope.selected;
            };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">

  
<select ng-model="selected" ng-change="setPageSize()">
                    <option class="resultsList" value="4">4</option>
                    <option class="resultsList" value="8">8</option>
                    <option class="resultsList" value="12">12</option>
                </select>
  
  

    <p>Changed to:  {{change || 'nothing'}} <p>
</body>
</html>
```